# Get data from subcollection in firestore flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In the 1st screen shot there are many documents in collection ***users***. Each documents contains further collection ***jobPost*** and that collection contains further documents and its meta data.

[image]

[image]

What I want here is go to the every document of collection ***users*** and further subcollection ***jobPost*** and fetch all the documents.
Suppose first it should go to document 1 in collection ***users***, in the document 1 it should fetch all the documnets in subcollection ***jobPost*** then it should go to the 2nd document of collection ***users*** and then get all the documents in the subcollection ***jobPost*** and so on. what will be the query or implementation to this technique

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're describing is known as a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), which allows you to query all collections with a specific name. Unlike what the name suggests, you can actually read all documents from all subcollections named `jobPost` that way with:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('jobPost').get()...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. If you've tried the collection group query and can't get it to work, edit your question to [show what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: I have just restart and it is working thanks man

Comment: can you tell me how to use inequality query with orderBy such as (_firestore
        .collection('workerField')
        .where('uid', isNotEqualTo: getCurrentUser().uid)
        .orderBy('orderBy', descending: true); )

Comment: the .where and .orderBy should be just before the . get

Answer (score 0):

When performing a query, Firestore returns either a QuerySnapshot or a DocumentSnapshot.

A QuerySnapshot is returned from a collection query and allows you to inspect the collection.

To access the documents within a QuerySnapshot, call the docs property, which returns a List containing DocumentSnapshot classes.

But subcollection data are not included in document snapshots because Firestore queries are shallow. You have to make a new query using the subcollection name to get subcollection data.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            FirebaseFirestore.instance
               .document(doc.id)
               .collection("jobPost")
               .get()
               .then(...);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**
if you not have field in first collection document then its shows italic thats means its delte by default otherwise if you have field in first collection document then you can access it easily so this is the best way that i share
**

```
static Future<List<PostSrc>> getAllFeedPosts()async
  {
    List<PostSrc> allPosts = [];
    var query= await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts").get();
    for(var userdoc in query.docs)
      {
        QuerySnapshot feed = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts")
            .doc(userdoc.id).collection("userPosts").get();
        for (var postDoc in feed.docs ) {
          PostSrc post = PostSrc.fromDoc(postDoc);
          allPosts.add(post);
        }
      }
    return allPosts;
  }
```