# Get detail information from master-detail collection in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, collections

I have created a simple app using flutter and firebase firestore database. There are 'users' collections and each user has 'posts' collections. Each post may have one or more posts added by different users.
I am trying to get all the posts regardless of users. However, my current function was written for reading records only shows the posts relevant for login user, not all the posts.

```
      Stream<QuerySnapshot> readItems({required String collectionName}) {
    CollectionReference detailCollection = _firestore
        .collection(mainCollectionName!)
        .doc(userUid)
        .collection(collectionName);

    return detailCollection.snapshots();
  }
```

Here, I pass 'users','login user's uid' and 'posts' as mainCollectionName, userUid and collectionName respectively. Can anybody guide me how do I get all the posts regardless of users?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After searching I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67496234/5319542). The following method gives the desired output.

```
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> readItems({required String collectionName}) {
    Query<Map<String, dynamic>> detailCollection = _firestore.collectionGroup(collectionName);

    return detailCollection.snapshots();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get all sub collections data from all the documents in a collection. Try this way

```
_firestore
  .collection(`${mainCollectionName}/*/${collectionName}`)
  .get()
```

Refer to this page for more details about querying collections and sub collections - https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html

Comment: Thanks, @Raj Kumar, But your solution was not woked for me.