# Firestore how to access subcollection inside docs map (Flutter)

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to access the subcollection 'match' using docs map.

[image: firestore]

```
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('time').get();

firestore.docs.map((e) {
   DateTime dt = e.data()['time'];

   e.collection('match');     // How to access its subcollection
})
```

How can I access the subcollection 'match' on each document and at the same time accessing the 'time' field.

Comment: Did you check this link already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67496126/get-data-from-subcollection-in-firestore-flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `firestore` variable is a `Future<QuerySnapshot>` object, and you're missing an `await` or `then` to wait for the future to resolve:

```
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('time').get();
final snapshot = await firestore;
```

You can then access a subcollection of each `time` document with:

```
snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
   ...

   var matchCollection = doc.reference.collection('match');
})
```

You might also want to look at [using a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to read/query all `match` collections in one go.

Comment: If it's nested, so I have to use `await` many times? `var matchCollection = await doc.reference.collection('match').get();` `matchCollection.docs.map(){ ... };`